# How to call a function with a parameter

Tags: swift, function, swift-playground

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dJiH.jpg)

```
func loveCaclculator(number: Int)-> Int {

    Int.random(in: 0..<1000)
    return number
}

loveCaclculator(number)
print(loveCaclculator(number: 4))
```

I am getting an error "cannot find number in scope" in the debugger and I dont know how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the parameter `number` is not visible outside of the function.

Your code doesn't use the parameter anyway, and you have to assign the result of the function to a variable for example

```
func loveCalculator() -> Int {
    let number = Int.random(in: 0..<1000)
    return number
}

let result = loveCalculator()
print(result)
```

On the other hand if you want to pass the maximum number as parameter you have to write

```
func loveCalculator(maxValue : Int) -> Int {
    let number = Int.random(in: 0..<maxValue)
    return number
}

let result = loveCalculator(maxValue: 20)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is explicit : `number` is not defined at this point, don't you forgot to pass 4 as you did in the print statement ?

```
loveCaclculator(number: 4)
print(loveCaclculator(number: 4))
```